# AWS CLI Scan with placeholder

Tags: aws-cli, dynamodb-queries

With this scan I can get 1 item (it's a test item):

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name my_table --select "COUNT" 
  --filter-expression "attribute_type(sender.test, :v_sub)" 
  --expression-attribute-values file://expression-attribute-values.json
```

But when I try to use a placeholder instead the real path `sender.test` I get 0 items. What I'm doing wrong?

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name my_table --select "COUNT" 
  --filter-expression "attribute_type(#code, :v_sub)" 
  --expression-attribute-names '{"#code": "sender.test"}' 
  --expression-attribute-values file://expression-attribute-values.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could manage it with help of a colleague. This is the way:

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name my_table --select "COUNT" 
--filter-expression "attribute_type(#code.#cor, :v_sub)"
--expression-attribute-names '{"#code": "sender", "#cor": "custom:myAttribute"}' 
--expression-attribute-values '{":v_sub":{"S":"N"}}'
```

I had to use the path with 2 placeholder `#code.#cor` I was trying to create the path with only one.